# Rename text file with batch script

Tags: batch-file

Using a batch script, I'm trying to read the first 25 characters of the 2nd line of a text file and then use that string to rename the file. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: If any of the answers below was helpful, please consider marking your preferred one as accepted. See [this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for an explanation of why this is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Get the second line
(set /P line=& set /P line=) < theFile.txt

rem Rename the file
ren theFile.txt "%line:~0,25%.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

**To get the second line:**

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1" %%G IN (1234.txt) DO if not defined line set "line=%%G"
echo %line%
pause
```

**To Rename**

Much like other platforms, the easiest way to rename is to move/copy to the same place with a different name. I prefer using `ren` + [Link](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set bool = 1
for /f "skip=1" %%a in (file_to_read.txt) do (
    if %bool% == 1 (
        set rename=%%a
        ren c:\users\microsoft\desktop\file_to_rename.txt !rename:~0,25!.txt
        set bool = 0
    )
)
```

Comment: you  should also delay-expand `%bool%` (or use the `defined`trick like Joshpbarron)

Answer (score 0):

The following code extracts the demanded text portion of the input file given by variable `TextFile` and, if found and the second line is not empty, renames the file:

```
@echo off

rem Provide the input file here:
set TextFile=yourfile.txt

set TextLine=
for /F "usebackq skip=1" %%G in ("%TextFile%") do (
  if not defined TextLine set "TextLine=%%G")
if defined TextLine (
  echo Rename "%TextFile%" to "%TextLine:~,25%"?
  pause
  ren "%TextFile%" "%TextLine:~,25%"
)
```

There is a `pause` command to be able to check what is going to be renamed.

Answer (score -1):

My idea is that this is difficult in batch files, and much easier in PowerShell:

```
ren test.txt "$((gc .\test.txt)[1].Substring(0,25)).txt"
```